# Program_name: linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: c, makefile

I have 6 programs: HOSpital.c, GenPazienti.c, Triage.c, Paziente.c, Prestazione.c and Reparto.c.

No one of them includes any other.

How can i do the makefile?

I tried with:

```
all: HOSpital GenPazienti Paziente Prestazione Reparto Triage

HOSpital: HOSpital.o
    gcc -o HOSpital HOSpital.c

HOSpital.o: HOSpital.c 
    gcc -c HOSpital HOSpital.c

GenPazienti: GenPazienti.o
    gcc -o GenPazienti GenPazienti.c

GenPazienti.o: GenPazienti.c 
    gcc -c GenPazienti GenPazienti.c

Paziente: Paziente.o
    gcc -o Paziente Paziente.c

Paziente.o: Paziente.c
    gcc -c Paziente Paziente.c

Prestazione: Prestazione.o
    gcc -o Prestazione Pretazione.c

Prestazione.o: Prestazione.c 
    gcc -c Prestazione Prestazione.c

Reparto: Reparto.o
    gcc -o Reparto Reparto.c

Reparto.o: Reparto.c
    gcc -c Reparto Reparto.c

Triage: Triage.o
    gcc -o Triage Triage.c

Triage.o: Triage.c
    gcc -c Triage Triage.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

But if i change something and i type "make" i get the error:
"Program_name: linker input file unused because linking not done"

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a single example:

```
gcc -c HOSpital HOSpital.c
```

This will attempt to use `HOSpital` as an *input* file.

Either use the correct option to name the output file, `-o`, *and* name it correctly. Like in

```
gcc -c -o HOSpital.o HOSpital.c
```

Or don't specify the output file name at all, then the compiler will use the input source file and change the `.c` suffix to `.o`. Like in

```
gcc -c HOSpital.c
```

It's the same problem all over.

---

Not that it matters in the end, the rule is used so the object file will be built, but you don't actually *use* the object file:

```
gcc -o HOSpital HOSpital.c
```

Here you use the source file directly to create the program. I think you meant to use

```
gcc -o HOSpital.o HOSpital.o
```

And as with the previous problem, you make this mistake all over.

---

Finally some general tips.

First, build with more warnings enabled. It will help you in the long run to find mistakes in the code, and will help find out places where there's possible undefined behaviors. I recommend at least adding `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Then you don't need to list all the object files and their rules explicitly in the makefile. The `make` program already knows how to make e.g. object files through [*implicit rules*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).

That last point means you can shorten down the makefile to something like

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pipe
LD = gcc
LDFLAGS = -pipe

HOSpital: HOSpital.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

GenPazienti: GenPazienti.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Paziente: Paziente.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Prestazione: Prestazione.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Reparto: Reparto.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

Triage: Triage.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
```

The variable `$@` is the target of the rule, and the variable `$^` is all prerequisites. For e.g.

```
HOSpital: HOSpital.o
```

the variable `$@` is `HOSpital` and `$^` is `HOSpital.o`.